# Rails left join conditional

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

I don't know good way to write activerecord query to select necessary data.
I have Customer table, that has many items

```
Customers(id)
```

Item table, that belongs to customer(One customer can have an item, then this item can belong to another customer, so customer_id is the current customer)

```
Items(id, price, customer_id)
```

Line item (join table: items many-to-many orders)

```
LineItems(id, item_id, order_id, price, quantity)
```

Order has_many items through line_items.

```
Orders(id, total, status, customer_id)
```

Well, I want to get all items, that is not included to orders which do not have status 1, 2, 3(status is an integer field)

So I need join customer and items, then left join with orders with conditional(status is not included ...) through line_items table. How can I implement it via ActiveRecord. Or SQl. By the way: I use psql. 
Thanks.

**Question is Well, I want to get all items, that is not included to orders which do not have status 1, 2, 3(status is an integer field)**

Comment: Customer.joins(:items).includes(items: :orders).where.not(orders: {status: [1, 2, 3]})

Comment: But it seems I should add where clause to left outer join

Comment: Can you help me to write just raw sql query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Item.includes(:orders).where.not(orders: {status: [1,2,3]})
```

*You can check the generated SQL using [`to_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql)*

**EDIT**

To include `items` which do have an `order`:

```
Item.includes(:orders).where("orders.status NOT IN(?) OR line_items.item_id IS NULL",[1,2,3])
```

Comment: First of all, there are items, that do not have orders.

Comment: The result should include items, which do not have any orders. So an item can have order with status 0 or 4, or an item can not have any orders. I want to exclude only items, which have orders with status 1,2,3

Comment: @AndreyMoroz I have added an **EDIT**, just try that out.. I have not tested it.

Comment: And I want to do it trough Customer, so I want to filter them like Customer.active.....

Comment: Looks good, but I need join items to active customers. Customer has id, state and I should get items, that have customer with active state

Comment: Probably something like this: `Item.includes(:orders => :customer).where("orders.status NOT IN(?) AND customers.status = ? OR line_items.item_id IS NULL",[1,2,3], 'active')`